# Could not find method jacocoTestCoverageVerification()

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I want to make jacoco plugin to fail when test coverage is not enough. I use example from gradle page :
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("output/jacoco/customJacocoReportDir")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("output/jacoco/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.5
            }
        }

        rule {
            enabled = false
            element = 'CLASS'
            includes = ['org.gradle.*']

            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                value = 'TOTALCOUNT'
                maximum = 0.3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get error:

> Could not find method jacocoTestCoverageVerification() for arguments [build_4v41fim1xdl76q49oxk7mnylv$_run_closure6@18601994] on root project 'demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_tasks) for **Gradle version 3.4 or higher** :

> For projects that also apply the Java Plugin, The JaCoCo plugin automatically adds the following tasks:
>
> `jacocoTestReport [...]`
>
> `jacocoTestCoverageVerification [...]`

If the code block in your question shows your full `build.gradle` file, this would mean that you need to add the line that applies the Java Plugin (`apply plugin: 'java'`).

Of course, you could also add a task of type [`JacocoCoverageVerification`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification.html) called `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` to your build file on your own:

```
task jacocoTestCoverageVerification(type: JacocoCoverageVerification) {
    // configuration
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank your for ideas but I attached only relevant jacoco code to the question. I do apply java plugin in the real code.

Comment: When I create task as you suggest it gives me another error: Could not get unknown property 'JacocoCoverageVerification' for root project ....

Comment: Well, now the question that should have come first: Which version of Gradle or the Gradle Wrapper do you use? The `JacocoCoverageVerification` task type and therefor the default task `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` only exist since [version *3.4*](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_tasks). Versions *3.3* and below do not mention the task or task type in their docs, you can check the URL.

Comment: I set version as in the code in the question: toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812".

Comment: Yeah, this is the used version of the Jacoco tool. But what's your Gradle version? You can use `gradle --version` to find out.

Comment: The problem was that ,somehow, I had 2 versions of gradle installed. One of them was old. Your answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using latest version of gradle. This may solve your problem